Issues with SSL Manager Extension and Cipher Suites After Upgrading Mirth Connect from 3.11.0 to 4.5.1
Question:
I've recently upgraded my Mirth Connect installation from version 3.11.0 to 4.5.1, and I'm encountering several issues related to SSL and cipher suites. After the upgrade, I get the following errors in the logs:
ERROR 2024-08-02 06:23:18.400 [main] com.mirth.connect.server.ExtensionLoader: Extension "SSL Manager" is not compatible with this version of Mirth Connect and was not loaded. Please install a compatible version.
ERROR 2024-08-02 06:23:19.103 [main] com.mirth.connect.server.migration.Migrate4_0_0: In version 4.0.0, TLSv1.1 and the following cipher suites have been disabled by default to reflect the latest security best practices: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
ERROR 2024-08-02 06:23:19.103 [main] com.mirth.connect.server.migration.Migrate4_3_0: In version 4.3.0, the following cipher suites have been disabled by default to reflect the latest security best practices: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

Details:
This prompt appears during the upgrade process

I contacted mirth officials, and they said it might be because multiple IPs were bound. Now all the extra IPs have been cancelled, but when I started the clone machine to test the server, I still got an error.
Questions:

How can I resolve the compatibility issue with the SSL Manager extension?

Is there a compatible version available for Mirth Connect 4.5.1?

What steps should I take to ensure that the systems communicating with Mirth Connect can support the updated security protocols and cipher suites?

If necessary, how can I temporarily enable older protocols or cipher suites in Mirth Connect 4.5.1 while I work on updating other systems?


Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!
